# How to open email app and display text in label with a single click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table with an “accept” link in the first column. There is also another column with a label with pending. Therefore when “accept” is clicked the **pending** is updated to **accepted**.

This line was my original code. When the “accept” is pressed it is displayed.

```php
<a href="tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php
  echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=accept";
?>" class="accept">accept</a>
```

Then I added this line so that I can also send an email. What happens here is when the “accept” link is clicked, the default mail app opens, but the label does not get updated from “pending” to “accepted”.

```php
<a href='mailto:".$email."?Subject=PARENT%20INQUERY' "tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php
  echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=accept";
?>" class="accept">accept</a>
```

I've done a lot of research about this but hit roadblock after roadblock, so I really hope for your help in this.

Comment: It won't because `href` can have only one action. You can't have a `mailto:` action *and* a header request in the same anchor.

Comment: is there any other ways to do it

Comment: Sure, two links...

Comment: can`t this be done in any other method rather than having two links

Comment: You could do it with AJAX.

Comment: is it possible to explain how

Comment: please post html, including surrounding table, and relevant javascript attempts.

Comment: Not really, it's very involved. Go ahead and read more about using AJAX and then come back when you have a specific problem that can be replicated. StackOverflow is not a drive-thru code generation service.

Comment: See [Getting Started with AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to learn the principles. You could use it to tell the server that the row is now accepted, and to change that table cell to read "accepted".

Comment: Separately, I see the PHP syntax `.$email.` in the middle of your `href` attribute. This won't work; it will just make the email address contain the text `.$email.`. You need to wrap it in `<?=` `%>` tags instead so that the string `$email` is interpreted as PHP and echoed onto the page.

Answer (score 2):

An anchor tag can only have one link in it. However, you can set an href and onclick as follows:

```
<a href="mailto:info@example.com" onclick="alert('hi!');">Example</a>
```